# How to call the vivod method on button 2 click? Python Telebot

Tags: python, bots, telebot

I have a question. I am making a telegram bot that writes debts to a database. But I don't know how to make it possible to call the Vivod method by pressing the 2 button. And I also wanted to immediately ask if my code is at least a little bit correct?

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import sqlite3

token = telebot.TeleBot('-------------------------')
chelZapis = None


@token.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(mainParam):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('dbOplat.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS baza (id int auto_increment primary key, nikChela varchar(50), money int)')
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    bts = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    ButProdazha = types.KeyboardButton("Запись", token.register_next_step_handler(mainParam, prodazha))
    ButPokupka = types.KeyboardButton("Чекнуть долги", token.register_next_step_handler(mainParam, vivod))
    bts.add(ButProdazha, ButPokupka)
    token.send_message(mainParam.chat.id, 'Привет, залупа', reply_markup=bts)


def prodazha(message):
    token.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ник чела:')
    token.register_next_step_handler(message, zapNik)

def zapNik(message):
    global chelZapis
    chelZapis = message.text.strip()
    token.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сколько должен?')
    token.register_next_step_handler(message, dengi)

def dengi(message):
    dolg = message.text.strip()

    conn = sqlite3.connect('dbOplat.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO baza (nikChela, money) VALUES ("%s", "%s")' % (chelZapis, dolg))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    token.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Запись сделала успешно')



@token.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def vivod(viv):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('dbOplat.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM baza')
    a = cur.fetchall()

    info = ''
    for i in a:
        info += f'{i[1]}, {i[2]}\n'

    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    token.send_message(viv.message.chat.id, info)


token.polling(none_stop=True)
```

And if it’s not difficult, please tell me, I want to make a functional where, by clicking on an additional button, I write the name of a person and +500 or -500, the program would search for a person and add a debt to him or subtract, looking for him in the database

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to register `callback_query_handler` for `vivod`, because `register_next_step_handler` implicitly does something like that automatically here:

```
ButPokupka = types.KeyboardButton("Чекнуть долги", token.register_next_step_handler(mainParam, vivod))
```

Also, in `dengi` you use `chelZapis` which is not defined inside this function, but inside the previous one - `zapNik`. It will cause an error. To avoid it you can pass additional arguments to the next function when using `register_next_step_handler`. For example:

```
def zapNik(message):
    # do your stuff
    chelZapis = ... # define it
    token.register_next_step_handler(message, dengi, chelZapis=chelZapis)

def dengi(message, chelZapis):
    # do anything using variable chelZapis!
```

Apart from that from `telebot` point of view your code seems to be correct.
If something is not working, perhaps it's something inside `vivod`. Did you try logging your bot and see if `vivod` is executed and where it fails?

I would be happy to answer your additional question separately, if you make it clearer which buttons do you want when and what should they do exactly.